# Parse batch upload API, what does error code 107 mean?

Tags: parse-platform

Why can't I add objects using Parse batch bulk import API?

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
   "requests":[
      {
         "method":"POST",
         "path":"1/classes/Store",
         "body":{
            "storeNumber":3466,
            "storeLocation":{
               "__type":"GeoPoint",
               "latitude":-88.481369,
               "longitude":44.263837
            },
            "storeAddress":"4733 W. GRANDE MARKET DR. GRAND CHUTE  WI 54913 US"
         }
      },

...

      {
         "method":"POST",
         "path":"1/classes/Store",
         "body":{
            "storeNumber":119,
            "storeLocation":{
               "__type":"GeoPoint",
               "latitude":-122.171134,
               "longitude":37.444756
            },
            "storeAddress":"165 STANFORD SHOPPING CTR PALO ALTO  CA 94304-1409 US"
         }
      }
   ]
}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/batch
```

{"code":107,"error":"Method 'POST' to '1/classes/Store' not supported in batch operations."}

I have created a 'Store' object with matching column names/types but can't any any rows with the batch API.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the documentation I would guess it is because your `path` is invalid.

You need an extra "/" at the front, so `/1/classes/Store` instead of `1/classes/Store`.